# Using progressbar in a simple file manipulation program?

Tags: c#

How do I use a progress bar in a file modification program where the progress bar is increased every time when a file is processed and when all files are processed it reaches full value i.e. 100
I tried something like

```
string files=Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files) {
                    progressBar1.Value=progressBar1.Value+100/(files.Length);
                     //Do some modification
}
MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

But even after all files are processed the value of progress bar is still not full, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set the `progressBar1.Maximum` property to the number of files and just increment it by 1 on each iteration.

Comment: @DavidG But the number of files may vary.

Comment: Not `files.Length` though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the [`ProgressBar.Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) property to match the number of files, and then increment the value by 1 for each iteration of the loop:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

progressBar1.Maximum = files.Length;

foreach (var file in files) {
    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value+1;
    //Do some modification
}

MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Comment: Thanks mate. BTW, do you think putting `progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value+1;` after `//Do some modification` is a better approach?

Comment: It's not better or worse, it depends on what you're doing - you need to decide that.

Comment: @Bumba - if `//Do some modification` takes 5 minutes for each file, you can choose to either have the user say "why has it reached 100% but not actually finished?" (code shown in answer) or "why has it stayed at 0% and not even started?" (your change in the comments). Neither is obviously better than the other (time period exaggerated for effect)